# I can't compile JetEntityframeWork

Tags: jet-ef-provider

I wanna use the MS Access database as DbFirst in my project using JetEntityframeWork. I try to enable DbFirst according to the installation guide of JetEntityframeWork [here](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider/blob/master/docs/Enabling_db_first.md), but I can't.

this is my steps to enabling:

1. Download JetEntityframeWork v-6.2.0 source code from [here](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider).
2. Extract the zip file
3. Open my Visual Studio 2019 as Administrator and open the solution
4. Update "Install.cmd" (REGROOT) => "SET REGROOT=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\19.0_Config"
5. Compile the project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsvcr.jpg).

It return me an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5MVD.jpg).

```
Error1 : Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\123\JetEntityFrameworkProvider-master\Debug\JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll' could not be found

Error2 : Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command ""%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u "JetEntityFrameworkProvider"" exited with code 3.
```

Did I forget anything?
What should I do now?

Comment: You could just use the much more recent [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/) provider, which is also available on  [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/). It is .NET Standard 2.0 compliant, so it works with .NET Framework 4.6.1+ and .NET (Core) 2.0+. I recommend to use the latest prerelease (which works with EF Core 3.1.x). It does not require you to setup your machine in any way and scaffolding/DB First and migrations work as well (just by referencing the package from nuget.org).